# Update div with items on AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have div where I need to show some data

I have button. By button I show modal

Here is code of modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" data-backdrop="false">
<div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Создание вопроса</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            @Html.Partial("~/Views/Questions/CreateQuestion.cshtml")
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Here is code of script

```
<script>
var myFormDialog = $("containerForPartialView").dialog(
    { autoOpen: false, modal: true });
$("myButtonForShowDialog").button().on("click", function () {
    myFormDialog.dialog("open");
});
$('.click').on('click', function () {
    $('.content').toggle();
});
var counter = 0;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#save').click(function () {
        save();
        email_update();
    });
});
function save()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: 'Post',
        dataType: 'Json',
        data: {
            question1: $('#Question1').val(),
            question2: $('#Question2').val(),
            question3: $('#Question3').val(),
            question4: $('#Question4').val(),
            question5: $('#Question5').val(),
            question6: $('#Question6').val(),
            question7: $('#Question7').val(),
            question8: $('#Question8').val(),
            question9: $('#Question9').val(),
            question10: $('#Question10').val(),

        },
        url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Questions")',
        success: function (da) {
            if (da.Result === "Success") {

                window.location.href = da.RedirectUrl;

            } else {

                alert( 'Error'+ da.Message);
            }
        },
        error: function (da) {
            alert('Error');
        }
    });
}
```

Also I have script for saving and updating div

Here is code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    email_update();
});

function email_update() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("QuestionsList", "Questions")',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false,
        success: function (result) {
            var email = result;
            var edit = '@Url.Content("~/Images/Edit.png")';
            var delete_ = '@Url.Content("~/Images/Delete.png")';
            // console.log(result[0].Name);
            for (var i = 0; i <= email.length - 1; i++) {
                var arrow  = '@Url.Content("~/Images/plus_plus.png")';
                var questionHtml = '<div class = "title" style="margin-top:15px;margin-left:15px;margin-bottom:10px;">'
                    +
                    '<img class="click" src="'
                    + arrow
                    + '">' +
                    '<span class="test">' +
                    '<input type="text" class="testclass" readonly value="' +
                    result[i].Quest + '">' +
                    '<a style="margin-left:25px;">' +
                    '<img src="' + edit + '"/>' +
                    '<img style="margin-left:10px;" src="' + delete_ + '"/>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<div class ="content" style="margin-left:60px; width: 80%; height: 100px; background: white;">' +
                    '<div style="width: 100%">' +
                    '<div style="float:left; width: 50%;">' +
                    '<b style="margin-left: 40px;">' + "Время на ответ"  + '</b>' +
                    '<b>' + ":" + '</b>' +
                    '<span>' + "Время на подготовку" +'</span>'+
                    '</div>' +
                    '<div style="float:right; width: 50%;">' +
                    '<b>' + result[i].TimeForAnswer + '</b>' +
                    '<b>' + ":" + '</b>' +
                    '<b>' + result[i].TimeForReady + '</b>'+
                    '</div>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '</div>';
                $(".count").append(questionHtml);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

|

It works  well when page starts. But in modal it not works, I mean this code `email_update();` .

Comment: please define "not works". You get an error? Or it doesn't do what you expect? One obvious issue is that save() is run just before email_update(). If save completes successfully, it will redirect to another page (`window.location.href = da.RedirectUrl` in the "success" function). So anything that happens in JavaScript after that point is going to be lost. Since ajax is async, it's impossible to know whether the save() or email_update() function will complete first, but as soon as save() completes, you lose everything anyway due to the redirect.

Comment: value is saving totable, but div not updates. I need to update div when click button in modal @ADyson

Comment: I'm almost certain that's because of what I just explained above regarding your page refreshing after the "save" operation.

Comment: Okay, how I need to rewrite code? at first update and then save?@ADyson

Comment: don't refresh the page immediately after returning from the "save" ajax. What's the point of that anyway? If you're just going to redirect immediately, you might as well have used a full postback. Anyway, where does it redirect to? The same page with different parameters, or a different page entirely? The answer to that will help determine your possible options to fix it.

Comment: I don't need to refresh page. I need to refresh data in div@ADyson

Comment: then just remove the page refresh.

Comment: You mean `$('#save').click(function () {
            save();
            email_update();

    });`

instead of my code? @ADyson

Comment: huh? `$('#save').click(function () {
        save();
        email_update();
    });` _already is_ your code! No I mean what I already said: remove the redirect (i.e. remove `window.location.href = da.RedirectUrl` from the "success" function within the "save()" method.

Comment: Thank's it helps! @ADyson